# Non-zero $\mathrm{BV}$ function integrating to zero

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, functions, normed-spaces

Let $I=[0,1]$ and $\mathrm{BV}(I)$ be the space of all functions $f:I\to I$ with
$$||\cdot||_{\mathrm{BV}(I)}=\mathrm{var}_I(\cdot)+||\cdot||_{L^1(I)}.$$
I found a claim in a few papers that any 2-dimensional subspace of $\mathrm{BV}$ contains a non-zero function which integrates to zero. I was wondering how one may be able to prove this result. They seem to claim it is true without providing any reference to any book so I expect this to be a classical result in functional analysis. A reference or hint of the proof would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick two linearly independent $BV$ functions, say $f,g$. Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and consider
$$ \int_I (af+bg) = a \int_I f + b\int_I g. $$
Either $\int_I f=0$ (then we are already done), otherwise pick $a=-\frac{\int_I g}{\int_I f}$ and $b=1$, then $h=af+bg$ satisfies $\int_I h =0$. As $f,g$ are linearly independent, we get that $h$ is nonzero.

**Added:** This is really a question in linear algebra. If we cannot be bothered to do the actual computation, we can also argue by abstract nonesense. Namely, let $X$ be our $2$-dimensional subspace and consider the linear map
$$ \varphi: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f \mapsto \int_I f. $$
Then by the rank nullity theorem we have
$$ \mathrm{dim}(ker(\varphi)) = \mathrm{dim}(X)- \mathrm{dim}(\varphi(X)) \geq \mathrm{dim}(X) -\mathrm{dim}(\mathbb{R})=2-1=1. $$
Thus, there is nonzero element in the kernel, i.e. a nonzero function which integrates to zero.